# send and format image data form node.js to node c++ addon problem?

Tags: c++, node.js, opencv, node.js-addon

how to convert info[0] to uchar array??

js "uint8clampedarray"

->

info  `Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>`

info[0] `class v8::Local<class v8::Value>`

->

uchar data[]

->

cv::Mat or ZXing::ImageView

need use image uchar data[];

->

DecodeBarcodes(cv::Mat)
or
ZXing::ReadBarcodes(ZXing::ImageView, {})

get qrcode detect result

ZXing::Result Convert Json and return

```js
let addon = require("bindings")("addon.node");
// uint8clampedarray from front end browser
let imageData = [255,255,0,0,255,255.....]; // uint8clampedarray
addon.decodeQRcode(imageData )
```

```cpp
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "ReadBarcode.h" // ZXing-cpp

// return ZXing::ImageView
inline ZXing::ImageView ImageViewFromMat(const cv::Mat& image)
{
    using ZXing::ImageFormat;
    auto fmt = ImageFormat::None;
    switch (image.channels()) {
        case 1: fmt = ImageFormat::Lum; break;
        case 3: fmt = ImageFormat::BGR; break;
        case 4: fmt = ImageFormat::BGRX; break;
    }
    if (image.depth() != CV_8U || fmt == ImageFormat::None)
        return { nullptr, 0, 0, ImageFormat::None };
    return { image.data, image.cols, image.rows, fmt };
}

// return ZXing::Results
inline ZXing::Results DecodeBarcodes(const cv::Mat& image, const ZXing::DecodeHints& hints = {})
{
    return ZXing::ReadBarcodes(ImageViewFromMat(image), hints);
}

void DecodeQRcode(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &info)
{
  Isolate *isolate = info.GetIsolate();

  Local<Array> arr = Local<Array>::Cast(info[0]);
  printf("size %d\n", arr->Length());
  
  // convert info[0] to uchar array
  // uchar data[] = {}; <- from node js uint8clampedarray data convert ??
  // cv::Mat QRCodeImage(imgHeight,imgWidth, CV_8UC4, data);
  // auto results = ReadBarcodes(QRCodeImage);
  // convert ZXing::Results to js object?

  info.GetReturnValue().Set(results );
}
void Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports)
{
  exports->Set(context,
               Nan::New("decodeQRcode").ToLocalChecked(),
               Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(DecodeQRcode)
                   ->GetFunction(context)
                   .ToLocalChecked());
}
NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

Comment: Don't post huge code snippets that are totally irrelevant to your question, it makes your question very hard to read and people tend to skip it.
Edit your question to simply state "How do I convert the `info[0]` passed by Node.js/V8 to a C++ `uchar` array". Everything else is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
Nan::TypedArrayContents<uchar> contents(info[0]);
if (contents.length() < min_length) printf("not good\n");
uchar *data = *contents;
```

And of course you will need to protect it from the garbage collector if you are going to be using this data after you have returned to your JS caller.